Implement ActionBar when my Activity is not inheriting AppCompatActivity()
My Kotlin file looks like this:
class MyActivity : JustACustomActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    // Set the custom toolbar as the action bar
    // For example, you can set the title and navigation icon programmatically
    toolbar.title = "Your Title"
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back_24)

    // Handle navigation click to mimic back button behavior
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }
}

And my xml layout looks like this:

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

<!-- Add your content below the toolbar -->

But when I run this i got the null pointer error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)

Is there any way i can implement an action bar with this setup?
